# transform | separated values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to trasform the data string reported below into a dictionary with the timestamp (first numeric element) as the keys. How can I do that?

```
element=20151201091000|22844.4|22786.2|22801.6|22839.7|1091
     element=20151201091500|22839.6|22798.3|22837.9|22801.7|477
         element=20151201092000|22800.4|22770.3|22799.1|22772.7|420
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily without a regex:

```
s = """element=20151201091000|22844.4|22786.2|22801.6|22839.7|1091
element=20151201091500|22839.6|22798.3|22837.9|22801.7|477
element=20151201092000|22800.4|22770.3|22799.1|22772.7|420"""



def pairs(s):
    for line in s.splitlines():
        spl = line.split("=")[1].split("|")
        yield spl[0], spl[1:]

print(dict(pairs(s)))
```

Or using python3 you can unpack:

```
def pairs(s):
    for line in s.splitlines():
        k,*vals = line.split("=")[1].split("|")
        yield k, vals


print(dict(pairs(s)))
```

Both will give you:

```
{'20151201091000': ['22844.4', '22786.2', '22801.6', '22839.7', '1091'], '20151201091500': ['22839.6', '22798.3', '22837.9', '22801.7', '477'], '20151201092000': ['22800.4', '22770.3', '22799.1', '22772.7', '420']}
```

If you want to cast:

```
def pairs(s):
    for line in s.splitlines():
        k,*vals = map(float, line.split("=")[1].split("|"))
        yield k, vals


print(dict(pairs(s)))
```

Output:

```
{20151201091000.0: [22844.4, 22786.2, 22801.6, 22839.7, 1091.0], 20151201092000.0: [22800.4, 22770.3, 22799.1, 22772.7, 420.0], 20151201091500.0: [22839.6, 22798.3, 22837.9, 22801.7, 477.0]}
```

Comment: Well, that's amazing, thanks for sharing this with me!!

Answer (score 0):

let `lines` be your string, i.e.

```
>>> print(lines)
element=20151201091000|22844.4|22786.2|22801.6|22839.7|1091
     element=20151201091500|22839.6|22798.3|22837.9|22801.7|477
         element=20151201092000|22800.4|22770.3|22799.1|22772.7|420
```

Now we can use `re` and a dictionary comprehension to build your desired dictionary, where I assume that the key is supposed to be an `int` and the values lists of `float`s. I also assume that the integer before the first '|' character in each line is your desired key.

```
>>> import re
>>> {int(re.search('^.*?(\d+)|', s).group(1)) : map(float, s.split('|')[1:]) for s in lines.split('\n')}
{20151201091000: [22844.4, 22786.2, 22801.6, 22839.7, 1091.0], 20151201092000: [22800.4, 22770.3, 22799.1, 22772.7, 420.0], 20151201091500: [22839.6, 22798.3, 22837.9, 22801.7, 477.0]}
```

Comment: @DiegoDiTommaso No problem, remember that you can accept your favorite answer if your question was answered sufficiently.